# Extend spline highchart beyound the series points

Tags: highcharts

I am working on spline chart and want a spline chart from a series as below pictures.
[image: below] [image: below]

But in the spline generated from high-chart was starting form first point upto the last point in series, How to make the spline start from left of first point and extending upto right of last point ,
the path beyond should be continuous as shown in figure

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    styledMode: true
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Styling data labels by CSS'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        borderRadius: 2,
        y: -10,
        shape: 'callout'
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 500,
    }, {
      y: 400
    }, {
      y: 500,
    }, {
      y: 400
    }]
  }]

});
```

```css
@import "https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css";
#container {
  height: 400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.highcharts-data-label-box {
  fill: #a4edba;
  stroke: gray;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.highcharts-data-label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.highlight .highcharts-data-label-box {
  fill: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: black;
}

.highlight.highcharts-data-label text {
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `pointPlacement: 'on'` property to set the points at extremes.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
        pointPlacement: 'on'
      }
    },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j2tnvzfw/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement